# Manually add a cookie in browser session in iE

Tags: javascript, cookies

**I want to add a cookie to the browser's session for testing that particular page.** I am able to do that in Chrome and Firefox, as there is an option to add a cookie manually in the Developer tools -> Application -> Cookies. But in IE there is no particular way to add a cookie. **Is there any way I can do that in IE?**. This is what I have tried so far. From suggestions from a few people, I tried to do the following.

1) Use `javascript:document.cookie="NAME=VALUE"` in the page I want to add a cookie. When I refresh the page, I don't find the cookie anymore.

2) Also tried after the page loaded to do `document.cookie="NAME=VALUE"` in the console.

Both of the solutions doesn't seem to work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just add it artificially with javascript declaration `document.cookie = "";`**

*Note: This snippet won't work on StackOverflow, because of jsfiddle sandbox mode.*

```js
document.cookie = "username=Test Subject";
document.getElementById('showcookies').addEventListener('click', function(){
  alert("Cookies JSON:" + document.cookie);
});
```

```html
<button id="showcookies">Show coowkies!</button>
```

Alternatively add it in your HTML using the `<script></script>` tags.

---

**Additionally, check if your version of IE browser has cookies enabled in it's properties.**

[image]